# how to apply LIKE %% to variable?

Tags: php, mysql

How can i apply LIKE to my query.

```
$query_event ="SELECT * FROM event_list WHERE even_title='$EventTitle' AND even_loc='$EventLocation' ";
```

now suppose there is form which requires either put title or put location in the form or u can put both so what will be the query?

Please help

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following format and always escape inputs using mysql_real_escape_string

```
$query_event ="SELECT * FROM event_list 
              WHERE even_title LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($EventTitle)."%' 
              AND  even_loc LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($EventLocation)."%'";
```

Comment: But bear in mind that this would need escaping, to avoid problems with quotes (SQL injection attacks, etc.) For example, what if $EventLocation was "Mick's Pub" -- now you have mismatched quotes in your SQL. (Aha -- thanks for adding the necessary escape function!)

Answer (score 1):

you want something like :

```
$query_event ="SELECT * FROM event_list WHERE even_title LIKE ('%".$EventTitle."%') AND even_loc LIKE ('%".$EventLocation."%')";
```

make sure to go through [these tutorials](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/) there is a `LIKE` tutorial too

Answer (score 1):

Well first, you want to prevent your SQL from injection but you can do this:

```
$query_event = "SELECT * FROM event_list 
   WHERE even_title LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($EventTitle)."%' 
   AND even_loc LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($EventLocation)."%'";
```

But you would actually be better of using something like PDO:

```
$qry = 'SELECT * FROM event_list 
   WHERE even_title LIKE :title 
   AND even_loc LIKE :location';

$data = array( 'title' => '%'.$EventTitle.'%', 
               'location' => '%'.$EventLocation.'%' );

$sth = $pdo->prepare($qry);

$sth->execute($data);
```

Comment: Misplaced $, looks like its fixed now +1

Comment: (Unless you've got ANSI quotes turned on, in which case MySQL won't like the string being delimited with double quotes rather than single quotes in the first example.)

Comment: @Matt, its always been fine for me, I will switch the example though.

Comment: @John Cool, just thought I'd mention it. I'm more sensitive to the issue because I also work with SQL Server and Oracle, and it's only single quotes that'll work in all situations with all of them. Typically double quotes are used for quoting object names, single quotes for actual strings.

Comment: @ to all, now suppose there is form which requires either put title or put location in the form or u can put both so what will be the query?

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as it seems. The `{}` are not even necessary but add readability for PHP without affecting the SQL validity.

```
$query_event ="SELECT * FROM event_list WHERE even_title LIKE '%{$EventTitle}%' AND even_loc LIKE '%{$EventLocation}%' ";
```